# Rails 5 - jQuery Autogrow plugin not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have absolutely no idea why some of the jQuery plugins are not working.

I've created a JS file called `autogrow.js` and placed it in `assets/javascript`.

In my `application.js` file I have included the line `//= require autogrow` after my jquery requires.

I proceed to copy the js file in the `dist` folder of the jquery plugins and paste it into `autogrow.js`. However, it still isn't working. I have tested it with 2 different autogrow plugins which i would like to use. They can be found [here](https://github.com/ro31337/jquery.ns-autogrow) and [here](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize).

(For what its worth, some other jquery plugins are working when i do this. However, these 2 in particular which i would like to use either one of them are not working.)

What am I missing?

**Update For Clarity:**

The first thing I did was added in a little "test" function into `autogrow.js` to see if it works:

```
function testing() {
  alert("Autogrow.js is being loaded");
};
```

I then proceed to call it in my view `foo/new.html.erb` and sure enough, there is an alert. I believe this is sufficient reasons to believe that `autogrow.js` has been loaded.

Next, I copy the entire js file from `dist/jquery.ns-autogrow.js` which can be found [here](https://github.com/ro31337/jquery.ns-autogrow/blob/master/dist/jquery.ns-autogrow.js) and paste the code into my `autogrow.js` file.

Lastly, I attempt to test autogrow in my `foo/new.html.erb` view as such:

```
<%= text_field_tag :input, nil, placeholder: "Test", class: "autogrow-field" %>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".autogrow-field").autogrow();
});
```

However, the text field does not autogrow.

Comment: Rather incomplete question. What do you mean "not working"? Is it not being loaded into sprockets? Is the file being loaded fine, but not behaving as you'd expect it to? How are you trying to initialize whatever field with the autogrow? Where are you binding autogrow, and to what selector?

Comment: @JoshBrody I have updated my question for clarity (i hope)

Comment: sorry for the late reply — pop open your developer console / javascript console and after the page is loaded, fire `$('input').autogrow();` and then see if it runs. I'm sure it's just an initialization problem.